# Rolling dice in a game consisting of 2 parts

Tags: probability, dice, bayes-theorem

We have six dice and play the following game, which consists of two parts.

1. In the first part we determine the number N of dice to be used in the second part.
2. In the second part we roll N dice and take the sum of points S shown by the N dice.

We can see N and S as random variables and we can describe outcomes of a round by the values of N and S. Determine the following probabilities:

(i) Determine
P[S = 2].

(ii) What is the probability that 1 die was rolled given that the sum shown is 2? That is, determine
P[N=1|S =2].

Hint: Remember Bayes’ Law.
(iii) What is the probability that the sum is 2, given that an even number of dice was rolled? That is, determine
P[S =2|N is even].

(iv) What is the probability that an even number of dice was rolled, given that the sum is 2?
That is, determine P[N is even|S =2].

I have the following ideas: the number of possibilities to obtain a given sum depends on the number of dice being rolled. For the question i, I can use the low of total probability but I do not know how to apply it since the number of dice is non defined. For example, I can have a sum of 2 by having 2 dice, each with a probability of 1/6 to land on 1. Therefore the total probability will be 1/36. Or by having one die landing on 2 with probability 1/6. But I do not know how to count the total probability given the 6 dice. Maybe you can help me clarify my ideas.

For the other questions I can use the Bayes' Law, but also here I have the same problem of considering the number of dice.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Seems almost obvious, but can you confirm explicitly: in the first step, you throw *one* die and take the number on the die as $N$, is that right?

Comment: @StinkingBishop what I understand is that the number of dice is chosen arbitrarily in the first step, but now that you've pointed it out it's getting confusing.... it is a question from my last exam that I could not solve